# Sphinx Error: No field 'sphinx_internal_class_name' found in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

## The Issue

I'm using Sphinx Search (2.0.8) for my Rails 3.2.8 web application using the gem Thinking Sphinx (3.0.4, directly from branch master on GitHub). Lately, when I've tried to search anything I get the following error:

```
index group_core,project_core,user_core: query error: no field 'sphinx_internal_class_name' found in schema
```

Online, the advice I found was to run a `rake ts:rebuild`, which I did, but the error is still appearing.

## Code

My thinking_sphinx.yml file is as follows:

```
development:
 morphology: stem_en
 enable_star: true
 charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F"
test:
 morphology: stem_en
 enable_star: true
 charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F"
production:
 morphology: stem_en
 enable_star: true
 charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F"
```

My index files are under app>indices, and they are as follows:

**group_index.rb**

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :group, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :name, :sortable => true
  indexes :description, :sortable => true

  #has post_id, user_id, created_at, updated_at

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

**user_index.rb**

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :last, :sortable => true
  indexes :first, :sortable => true
  indexes :preferredname, :sortable => true
  indexes :email, :sortable => true

  #has post_id, user_id, created_at, updated_at

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

**project_index.rb**

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :project, :with => :active_record do
  indexes :name, :sortable => true
  indexes :pitch, :sortable => true

  #has post_id, user_id, created_at, updated_at

  set_property :delta => true
end
```

I've searched online, and nothing I've found (rebuilding the index, upgrading to the most recent version of Thinking Sphinx, etc.) has solved this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this bug is fixed in recent commits on the master branch. Can you try the following?

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.0.5',
  :git    => 'git://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx.git',
  :branch => 'master',
  :ref    => '41a248c926'
```

Comment: I think you're right. I just downgraded back to 3.0.4, and it works as expected again. Thanks!